# Rubymine can't find SDK. Where is it?

Tags: rubymine

I have just installed rubymine 5.4.3.2.1 and am trying to start an example project. The problem i am having is that rubymine is asking for a SDK. So where do i point it to?

Comment: What operating systems are you on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are on windows its where ever you installed ruby under the bin folder as diplayed [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-ruby-sdk.html)  If you are on a unix base system go to the terminal and enter `which ruby` and you will point it to the directory listed. Assuming you have [ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) installed

Comment: Ok cool so I pointed it to C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1\bin\rubymine.exe and it accepted it. Now I am getting a 'rubygems is required' from it. I got a bunch of errors when I pressed apply, probably because it couldnt find rubygems so I am downloading from here http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ is that right? and yes I am on a Windows machine

Comment: restarted rubymine and then went through the SDK selecting process again and found a bunch of them I could use after installing the rubyinstaller.org file... so cheers for that

Answer (score 17):

You should point it to the where you keep your **Ruby Binary File**, for example:

- Windows - `d:\dev\Ruby19\bin\ruby.exe`
- Mac Brew - `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby`
- Ruby Version Manager - `/Users/<user>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby`
- Linux/Mac Default - `/usr/bin/ruby`

If you are on Windows and don't have Ruby installed yet, download it from http://rubyinstaller.org/ .

After installing point RubyMine to the `ruby.exe` file location.

---

For example, if you install using `rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p247.exe` into `c:\Ruby200` (the default path suggested by the installer), RubyMine would accept `c:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe` path for the SDK (it will even detect it automatically):

[image: Ruby SDK]

Note that it's also recommended to [install and configure](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) the [DevKit](https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe) from the same site as it's required for many gems that have native code.

When everything is installed you can follow the [Quick Start Guide for RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/quickstart/).

Answer (score 3):

Only for `Mac, brew, rbenv`:

`$ which ruby
/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/ruby`

But it doesn't show used gems. So, it's better to add file inside ruby version folder: `/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/*your_version*/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby path in Rails Container: `/usr/local/bin/ruby` (no RVM installed)

Local Ruby path: `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby` (no default Ruby installed)

Local RVM path: `~/.rvm/bin/rvm`

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you add a remote interpreter using rbev, just add the path you get via this command:

```
which ruby
```

and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you have installed the correct Ruby, I've found that invalidating caches and restarting RubyMine can clear this up. You'll find this option on the File menu.

I'm not sure *why* this works, but it definitely fixed this exact problem for me today.

Answer (score 0):

If you using WSL and asdf:
/home/<your_user>/.asdf/installs/ruby/<your_version>/bin/ruby