# RubyMine doesn't recognize my Ruby installation path

Tags: ruby, scripting, installation, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I've made a custom sient installer of **Ruby 2.0** with some *gems* and *extras*, my installer expands all the **Ruby** files to **c:\Program Files (x86)\Ruby**, the interpreter (**ruby.exe**) is in the **Bin** folder, all is as normally but just it's not an original installation, I expand the files and I add the registry keys to associate files by my own, I can run Ruby as normally ever I want.

Now, is the first time that I try the **JetBrains RubyMine** IDE, and I can't found a simple guide which explains how to set the Ruby directory, seems that this IDE assumes that the Ruby installation is original and maybe takes a registry value from the original Ruby installer to know the Path or something, I don't know, but just I didn't see any help about how to set the Ruby directory manually.

(I have the same problem for PyCharm)

Anyways I've tried to set it from the **Ruby SDK and Gems** option, the dialog-box says "select Ruby interpreter Path", but I'm on the Path and it's not recognized, I mean that the **Ok** button still disabled:

[image]

Then I'm missing the right option anywhere? or really a professional and expensive IDE like this doesn't has support just to specify the location of **Ruby** in these circunstance where an user does not use the original Ruby installer? *I really will think not*.

Comment: Do you need to provide Rubymine with the path to your the ruby executable or the path that contains the bin directory directory?

Comment: Note to Future Visitors: For help locating your Ruby SDK or installing one, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17950454/1366033)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience it is more preferable to set your PATH environment variables appropriately instead of trying to locate executables on a per-app basis.

You can set your path so that the desired Ruby takes precedence over any other rubies and I am sure that RubyMine will pick it up (or just use ruby and let your PATH specify which to use).

On another note you might also want to have a look at a ruby version manager such as rbenv or RVM.

**Update**: Just tried to set manually a Ruby SDK in the latest version of RubyMine (6.3) and it worked as expected. I had, however, to expand the folder in which the binary resided (in your case `bin`), select the actual binary and then click OK. Have you tried that as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two JRuby versions installed and one of them is not recognized:

- Add both bin directories to your `PATH` (like in Kostas Rousis's answer above),
- set `JRUBY_HOME` to the one version you want to use and
- restart RubyMine.

In my case, I have the version 1.6.8 and 9.1.13.0 installed. Setting `JRUBY_HOME` to the newer version I can use both versions. However setting `JRUBY_HOME` to the older version, RubyMine only recognises the older version, even when I navigate to the newer version's folder. That's a really weird behavior but I'll take it. I still remember that it worked properly in earlier versions of RubyMine though (I'm currently at 2017.2.4).