# PyCharm doesn't recognize my Python installation path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

This is the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125024/rubymine-doesnt-recognize-my-ruby-installation-path) else but for **Python**.

The thing is that I've built my own installer package of Python interpreter (I've added modules and extras) and once installed I can't find the way to set the location of my custom Python installation dir in **PyCharm** *IDE*, I can't find any option to manually specify the location of python interpreter.

While I don't know if exist that option I'm thinking in other alternative, If maybe the **PyCharm** IDE takes the original Python path from a registry value then it should be sufficient for set the location, but I don't know if pycharm uses a config file or a reg key to get the python location and where is this value to modify it, I need help.

PS: I'm having the same problem for **RubyMine** *IDE*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For **PyCharm**, in the IDE go to ***File*** -> ***Settings***. In the *Project Settings* navigation panel, select ***Project Interpreter*** and then ***Python Interpreters***, then in the right panel, click on the green plus (***+***) icon on the top right and select ***local***. Navigate to the python executable you would like to specify as your interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, unfortunately for RubyMine IDE is totally different and I'm lost :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't have RubyMine, but the platform itself is supposed to be the same for all JetBrains IDEs. I'm sure there is a simple way to add a local interpreter.. take a look at [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-available-ruby-interpreters.html), it might help.

Comment: That's what I currently tried to do, but when I select my "ruby.exe" interpreter I still can't see the basic methods such as "print", etc. Anyways Thanks again, i will write a new question bout this

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

- click on **File**
- select **Settings** from the menu
- in new Settings window click on **Project** and then **Python interpreter**
- click on **gear icon** on the right, then on **Add...** option
- in the **Add python interpreter** window select **System interpreter** from the list on the left
- pick **Python**, click apply and you are done

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar problems with PyCharm. 
Having installed both Python 2.7 and 3.5 I was only able to find the the "python.exe" file for python 2.7.

I tried reinstalling Python 3.5 and attempting to change the installation path to C:// but it lead to several errors. This is the work around I found for getting 3.5 on PyCharm as an interpreter.

[Copy the python 3.5 directory in windows explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK26M.png)

[Paste it into PyCharms choose local interpreter area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2jIJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I have a MacBook Pro 2020. This solved it for me.
NOTE make sure python is installed.

1. Pycharm Preferences
2. Add interpreter
3. Add local interpreter
4. Go to terminal and type  -> which python3
5. Copy the address and go back to pycharm
6. Press Existing
7. Press the three dots and add the address in there and find the install location
   Press ok and then you should find the new interpreter.