# PyCharm can no longer find my Python installation

Tags: python, pycharm

My PyCharm ver was working fine, but I broke it.

I wanted to have the matplotlib, so I uninstalled my Python installation and installed [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/), which works fine. But it was installed in the folder where installation program was (i.e. download folder).

When I try to run a python program in PyCharm a message comes up saying

> Cannot run program c:\python34\python.

I tried to Google "how to change python directory" and came up with the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180646/pycharm-doesnt-recognize-my-python-installation-path) in Stack Overflow:

> In project settings Select Project Interpreter and then Python Interpreters

My project settings does not have a tab for Project Interpreter, it has:

- Appearence
- Editor
- Plugins
- Version Control
- Project: bitcoin
- Build, Execution
- Frameworks
- Tools

Comment: Please learn how to use formatting on Stack Exchange network websites. It's incredible you have so much reputation while totally ignoring such an essential thing.

Comment: Also, please don't forget to specify which version do you use. My answer is for PyCharm 2016.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

It's **Project: (project name)** → **Project Interpreter** → "Gear" icon → **Add local**.

[image: Project: (project name) → Project Interpreter → **Gear** icon → Add local]

This change will affect your current project only. To change the default interpreter for new projects, go to **File** → **Default Settings...**.

Also, there's a search box on top of the setting window. Use it if you can't find some option.

---

Or you can try [registering WinPython as a standard Python distribution](https://winpython.github.io/#portable).

[image: Registering WinPython as a standard Python distribution]