# RubyMine - No Ruby interpreter configured for the project

Tags: ruby, windows, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I go to Settings - Ruby SDK and Gems, and pick out `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe`.

It loads up a bunch of gems on the right side, and looks like it's going to work.

I hit OK, and still have awful syntax highlighting and it still thinks it has no Ruby interpreter.

I've tried invalidating the cache, and even downloading a new version of ruby and pointing it to the new binary ruby.exe file.

Comment: Note to future visitors: For help locating your Ruby SDK or installing one, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17950454/1366033)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I faced this problem when I moved my project to another PC running a different version of JRuby. resolution:

1. close RubyMine
2. delete `.idea/` folder
3. re-open project in RubyMine

Comment: Thanks! it helps and should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: I rebuilt Ruby-2.2.4, did everything I could think of with my path and had nearly given up on RubyMine then I found this. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks. A bit surprising to see that this issue is persistent even after two years.

Comment: I cloned a fresh repository and still got this error. Removing the .idea folder solved the problem. Thanks!

You can find the .idea folder under the root folder of your repository/project.

Comment: I switched from IntelliJ, after deleting `.idea` it worked in RubyMine. Thanks!

Comment: i had this issue when creating a project with the `idea` command-line launcher from an older version (2021.3) after upgrading to a newer one (2022.2). deleting `.idea/` then updating the launcher and using the new one worked fine.

Comment: It worked in my Mac M1

Comment: It worked for me too. Anyone checking this solution, please give emphasis on step 1. "Close RubyMine". I tried doing it from the terminal inside Ruby and for obvious reasons, it didn't work. After closing RubyMine everything worked just fine :)

Comment: This happened to me too on a brand-new install of RubyMine and `rbenv` in 2023. Thanks for the fix!

9 years and counting, lol...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when git somehow got confused about whether files in RubyMine's .idea directory were in git or not. Doing things like `git stash` would clobber my RubyMine configuration. I fixed it by recloning my repo, copying .idea from the old clone to the new, and fixing my RubyMine configuration. After that it stayed fixed.

No idea whether that's why you're having this problem, but I'd look in to whether RubyMine is having any trouble writing files to .idea, or whether anything is changing those files behind RubyMine's back.

Comment: Don't check in your .idea folder and you won't have this problem.

Comment: I do check in most of .idea, because it takes a while to correctly set up a project, but some files change too often and/or are machine-specific so can't be checked in. My problem occurred after removing one of those files from git. I don't recall which.

Answer (score 0):

Highly suggest if you're going to check in the .idea folder (I would ignore it personally) try using this gitignore to configure it correctly: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

Comment: I don't know how this answer was relevant, but I disagree. Here is jetbrains' recommended .gitignore file: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1192

Comment: That thread is 2 years old and doesn't discuss RubyMine 6. It's relevant because a good gitignore would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on my Windows system. What worked for me was setting up a Remote Ruby Interpreter, which is very easy to set up.
Click on `Project Structure > Project > SDK > Add SDK > Ruby SDK > Remote Interpreter or Version Manager`. Here, Select `WSL` option and the Linux distribution you want.

Instead of Project structure, you can also directly click on the Configure button next to the error message.