# Rubymine: No Ruby interpreter configured for the project

Tags: rubymine

I am using RubyMine  on Mac OSX, and it reminds me that "No Ruby interpreter configured for the project." But when I configure it on the Preferences, it won't let me save the configuration, see the image below. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454272/rubymine-no-ruby-interpreter-configured-for-the-project#?